# How do I unit test for an orderby clause in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, kendo-grid, moq

I have a LINQ query that's being returned from a service to a controller, then set as the data source for a Kendo Grid control.

The Kendo Grid control errors on the `ToDataSourceResult` method, with the error

> The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.

The error itself is fairly simple to solve, just add an `orderby` to the LINQ query; however, the unit tests for the service and controller didn't test this requirement, so my question is, should this be tested in the service unit test, the controller unit test, or in a to-be-written-in-the-future (where timeUntilThen <= daysInYear / 0) integration test?

If in a unit test, how exactly do I test for the presence of an `orderby` in the underlying LINQ query without just throwing a `.Skip()` at the result set?

We're using the Visual Studio built in testing tools, and Moq for mocking.

Comment: Well why not just "throw a skip at the result set"? If your requirement is to be able to call `Skip()` then surely the test would be to see if `Skip()` can be called?

Comment: @musefan I can, but that just feels like a bit of a dirty hack

Comment: You could check if your result set is IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx), `OrderBy` returns an `IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>`. That should be a good indication, if there has been an `OrderBy` applied on the result set or not.